# highstock grouping without zoom

Tags: highcharts

Can I use Highstock do the following:
Grouping by days, weeks, months, but to display all data. That is, make a button group, but that they did not zoom, and only group data (do approximation).

Comment: I feel a little bit confused, so you would like to display all data, but grouped data should also be displayed? it looks like strange. Could to describe your expectation in more details?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can update dataGrouping:

```
        $("#container").highcharts().series[0].update({
            dataGrouping: {
                units: [ ['year', [1]] ]   
            }
        });
```

And jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W7rTL/1/

Answer (score 0):

This works well when a lot of data, but when the data is small, such as a few months, the schedule is not grouped.

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/W7rTL/5/

Answer (score 0):

I get similar results when clicking the button but only on like a 3M range.  Strange, clicking button to go to "year" aggregation, it falls back to day (?).  This surprised me, as it isn't even one of the aggregation options in the data series (possibly code falls back to default)?  Once you've done this, if you then click to ALL or 1 year, it properly picks right back up to yearly aggregation...